# Ubuntu 17.10 (gnome shell) and workspaces grid previews

Tags: gnome-shell, workspaces

Is it possible, with gnome-shell, to get NxN workspaces (for example 3x3) with previews, like this was possible with unity ?

If yes, how ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can do it using the [Workspace Grid](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid) extension.

Do one of the following (reproduced from the [Installation](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid#installation) section):

> 1. Download the `.zip` file on the [Downloads page](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension/releases).
> 2. Open `gnome-tweak-tool`, go to "Shell Extensions", "Install Extension" and select the `.zip` file.
>
> Or
>
> 1. Visit https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/
> 2. Install by clicking the toggle switch
> 3. Hit the configuration button next to the switch (a page reload may be required).

Comment: Does this solution show previews of workspace while swithcing workspaces ?

Comment: @davcha No, but you're not going to get anything better unless you implement it yourself.

Comment: Where does one find the "Shell Extensions" item. On the left side of the `gnome-tweak-tool` I find an item with the name `Extensions`. Under this I see `Ubuntu appindicators` and `Ubuntu dock`. That is for Ubuntu 17.04.